# What is the difference between bzip2 and x-bzip2

Tags: http, http-headers, bzip2

In a HTTP response, a Content-Encoding header field can be bzip2 or x-bzip2

For example, you may get something like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: mon, 9 Mar 2016 22:38:34 GMT
...
Content-Encoding: bzip
```

or something like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: mon, 9 Mar 2016 22:38:34 GMT
...
Content-Encoding: x-bzip
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really none. As you can see in the [IANA Content Coding Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-parameters/http-parameters.xhtml#content-coding), `bzip2` and `x-bzip2` are no registered content codings. The preceding `x-` has been meant to stress out the unregistered nature of this coding (see also `x-gzip` vs. `gzip`). Interestingly, this pre-dates even RFC1945. [RFC1521, section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521#section-5) states:

> Implementors may, if necessary, define new Content-Transfer-Encoding
> values, but must use an x-token, which is a name prefixed by "X-" to
> indicate its non-standard status, e.g., "Content-Transfer-Encoding:
> x-my-new-encoding".

As far as support for it goes: To my knowledge Lighttpd is the only webserver with support for bzip2. I know for sure that elinks understands bzip2'ed content, but there should be others.

It is rather rare to see any actual use of this coding, as bzip2 is quite CPU-heavy and gzip is offering a better compromise between speed and compression ratio.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the difference is just that "bzip2" is the actual format, and "application/x-bzip2" is the MIME type. In other words, it's poh-tay-toh / poh-tah-toh -- they're the same thing.

[wikipedia link to bzip2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2)

[wikipedia link to archive formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats)